# Update toolStripStatusLabel1.Text via a property from an other window

Tags: c#, winforms

On my Main window i have a statusstrip and a public property to update the toolStripStatusLabel1.Text. From my main form this works. 
when i open a second form, put a button on it and then set the next code under the Mousemove event nothing happens. How can i show text int the toolStripStatusLabel1.Text when the mouse moves over a button from an other form

```
private void button_Login_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Form_Main Main_Window = new Form_Main();                 
    Main_Window.StatusstripText = "TEST...";
    Main_Window.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a control in one window form from other form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125235/how-to-access-a-control-in-one-window-form-from-other-form)

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new instance of Form_Main and hence do not see it working. You will need a reference to the original Form_Main and set the StatusstripText of it. You can do this either by passing it through a constructor or setting a property on the second form.

On your second form have a property called Parent as shown below.

```
public Form_Main Parent { get; set; }
```

Set the property when creating the second form.

```
SecondForm form  new SecondForm();
form.Parent = this;
form.Show();
```

Now, use this property to set the status strip text, from your second form.

```
private void button_Login_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     this.Parent.StatusstripText = "TEST...";
     Main_Window.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. The second form has a panel with a gradiënt color and this flickers now when the mouse moves over the button. I tried double buffers = true but this does not work. How to avoid the flickering?

Comment: I removed the refresh. The flickering stopped.